# Dynamically set Environment Variable for Selenium Chrome Hub in ECS Docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, selenium, docker, dockerfile, amazon-ecs

I have a cluster in AWS-ECS where I have custom image in ECR pulled which uses selenium/node-chrome from docker hub as a base image. This is the service I want to use as selenium node. I am passing 3 environment variable in it where one of the variable is REMOTE_HOST. I want to set it dynamically while docker image runs in ECS.

Following is the things I tried.

**DockerFile**

`FROM selenium/node-chrome:3.10.0
COPY init.sh /etc/profile.d/
RUN sudo chmod +x /etc/profile.d/init.sh`

**init.sh**

```
export EC2_HOST=$(wget -O - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4 2> /dev/null)
export REMOTE_HOST="http://$EC2_HOST:5555"
```

I was expecting that while docker is initiated, REMOTE_HOST would be available for the base docker image. But I do not see the environment variable being taken by the image nor I can see the variable value while I echo after connecting to the container (`docker exec -it <Container Id> bash`) in the EC2 instance.

Can anybody help me how do I set the environment variable dynamically?

I have also tried to use entrypoint as follow with no luck

`FROM selenium/node-chrome:3.10.0
COPY init.sh /etc/profile.d/
RUN sudo chmod +x /etc/profile.d/init.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["init.sh"]`

Comment: What do you mean by 'dynamically' ? Environment variables are applied to a task/container at start up and are not updated at runtime. If you modify environment variables while the task is running, you can get them to apply by stopping the task and starting a new one.

Comment: In simple language, I want to pass my EC2 Instance IP address to REMOTE_HOST environment variable dynamically when the nodes are auto scaled. We get it from this API (http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4) provided by AWS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't speak to why `/etc/profile.d/init.sh` does not get executed on container spinup, maybe that depends on what the linux base image is for selenium/node-chrome.

However, `ENTRYPOINT ["init.sh"]` will definitely not work because you're replacing the entry point script that selenium/node-chrome sets up. Instead you should try to add to it. I would edit your dockerfile to be:

```
FROM selenium/node-chrome:3.10.0
COPY init.sh /etc/profile.d/
RUN sudo chmod +x /etc/profile.d/init.sh
USER root
RUN sed -i '1 asource /etc/profile.d/init.sh' /opt/bin/entry_point.sh
USER seluser
```

The `sed` line adds the init.sh line to existing entry_point.sh on the second line, now when the container starts, you will see:

```
REMOTE_HOST variable is set, appending -remoteHost
```

Note though that when you start a new shell with `docker exec -it <id> /bin/bash` it doesn't necessarily inherit the same environment as the shell that selenium process is running in, echo may not work.

Comment: Thanks @RaGe. Now I now see the IP being taken by selenium Host. But there is still a small issue. Since I am adding http://$IPAddress:5555, I am getting java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in authority at index 7: http://10.94.88.212 :5555/wd/hub/status as error. I don't understand why there is space coming in between. I think Selenium server isn't taking the // characters correctly. Although I did try to change init.sh without any luck.                                                   `EC2_HOST=$(echo $EC2_HOT | sed 's/[^0-9^.]*//g')`

Comment: that's really a separate issue, you should open a new question.